# How to prevent multi select box from clearing items already selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi select drop-down that has previous selected items selected on page load. When the user clicks in the box without holding down the ctrl key the items are unselected. How do I prevent this. I have already tried various options including the simplest below. It gets to the alert but still clears the items and only the one the user clicked on is highlighted. I'm trying to prevent a user from clicking and clearing the previous items stored in the database that where highlighted if they click without holding the ctrl key.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#selectID").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("here");              
    });
});
```

Comment: I suggest not using a multi-select drop-down.  Build your own UI, making it clear those items can't be unselected.

Comment: I will suggest you use checkboxes instead

Comment: Unfortunately those two are not an option. Legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I used the following code to gather the selected values on page load and then on the first click, load the dropdown with the collected values.
The item clicked on is ignored but the user can start using the select after that like it normally functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var vals = $("#selectID").val();
    var x = 0;
    $("#selectID").click(function(){
        x = x + 1
        if (x <= 1){
            $('#selectID').val(vals);
        }
    });
});
```